# Android Realm version update error

Tags: android, realm

I just updated my Realm in my project then I got this error please help me to fix this error.

```
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing io/realm/package-info.class
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing io/realm/BaseRealm$1.class
Error:2 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your installed JDK version.

Comment: show your top level build gradle here.

Comment: I fixed that error. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that problem.

I Just disabled my instant run. Then when I try to enable, It shows to update my gradle. Then I updated it. And the problem is also fixed.
There was a migration problem at that time. And that was fixed by the code :

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
 .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
 .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Thank you.